почему python берёт строки вместо отдельных символов
есть такой скрипт:
import time

def exe (txt):
    for i in txt:
        print(i, end = "")
        time.sleep (0.01)
    print("", end = "\n")

exe ("i like trains")

он должен выводить текст побуквенно, но выводит по строке за раз

Во-первых у вас задержка слишком маленькая, вы её просто не заметите. Во-вторых вывод может буферизоваться, нужно добавить в печать параметр flush=True.
